# ContentResolver is inserting duplicate data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am trying to insert data into database through content resolver. The data is inserted but for each insert() there are two entries. I debug my code but couldn’t get the cause of duplicate entry.
Here are snippets of my code

insert() in content provider:

```
@Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        int uriType = uriMatch.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase mDb = dBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        long id = 0;
        switch(uriType){
        case Allowed_url:
            id = mDb.insert(DatabaseHandler.Names, null, values);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown uri" + uri);
        }
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
        return Uri.parse(Names_TABLE_PATH + "/" + id);
    }
```

code in content resolver:

```
    ContentResolver myResolver = mActivity.getContentResolver();

                                Uri browserProviderUri = Uri.parse("content://com.eaft.parentalcontrol." +
                                        "AllowedUrlProvider/" +
                                        "DatabaseHandler/NAMES");

                                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

                                System.out.println("History_AL.get(0).getUrl() is : " + 
                                        LightningView.History_AL.get(0).getUrl());
                                cv.put("NAME", LightningView.History_AL.get(0).getName());
                                cv.put("InTime", LightningView.History_AL.get(0).getInTime());
                                cv.put("OutTime", LightningView.History_AL.get(0).getOutTime());
                                myResolver.insert(browserProviderUri, cv);
                                System.out.println("myResolver.insert(browserProviderUri, cv) "  +
                                        myResolver.insert(browserProviderUri, cv));
LightningView.History_AL.remove(0);
```

Can anyone guide me to point out where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

megha you are calling "`myResolver.insert(browserProviderUri, cv);`" twice that's why it inserting the data two times.

Now just remove `myResolver.insert(browserProviderUri, cv)` from `System.out.println` statement.